# Else statement runs even if the "if" statements are true in PHP

Tags: php

I am having a problem where I am running multiple if statements. Even if the "if" statements are true, the else statement still runs afterwords for some odd reason. Any reason why this might be?

```
$userlength = strlen($username);
$emailength = strlen($email);
$passlength = strlen($password);

// VERIFICATION
if ($userlength < 10 || $userlength > 20) {
    Echo "Username Error";
}
if ($emailength < 7 || $emailength > 30) {
    Echo "Email Error";
}
if ($passlength < 5 || $passlength > 32) {
    Echo "Password Error";
}
if ($password != $repassword) {
    Echo "Passwords Do Not Match";
}
else {
    Echo "This still runs!?!?!!?";
}
```

Comment: This means that the passwords do match. The else is applied only against `$password != $repassword`

Comment: Obviously, (from the code) the only way that last block of code runs is if `$password` is indeed different from `$repassword`

Comment: Alright, now although I understand what you mean, how would I fix this so I get the desired results?

Comment: I understand that I can use else if, the only reason I don't want to is because I need it to be able to show all three errors at the same time.

Comment: Also @user3757779 You should not check the length of the email, but instead check if it is a *valid* email instead, by using regex or one of the `filter_var` functions:  [filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)](http://ch2.php.net/filter-var)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your final `else` is only in play for the final `if`; try using `else if` like this:

```
// VERIFICATION
if ($userlength < 10 || $userlength > 20) {
    echo "Username Error";
}
else if ($emailength < 7 || $emailength > 30) {
    echo "Email Error";
}
else if ($passlength < 5 || $passlength > 32) {
    echo "Password Error";
}
else if ($password != $repassword) {
    echo "Passwords Do Not Match";
}
else {
    echo "This still runs!?!?!!?";
}
```

But your logic is unclear. So perhaps you need to make it more robust like this. The idea is `$invalid` is set to `FALSE` and any error would set `$invalid` to `TRUE`. So if at the end of the checks `$invalid` is indeed `TRUE` you know you should stop what you are doing & loop back:

```
// VERIFICATION
$invalid = FALSE;
if ($userlength < 10 || $userlength > 20) {
    $invalid = TRUE;
    echo "Username Error";
}
if ($emailength < 7 || $emailength > 30) {
    $invalid = TRUE;
    echo "Email Error";
}
if ($passlength < 5 || $passlength > 32) {
    $invalid = TRUE;
    echo "Password Error";
}
if ($password != $repassword) {
    $invalid = TRUE;
    echo "Passwords Do Not Match";
}

if ($invalid) {
    echo "There were errors.";
    die();
}

echo "If you get to here, everything checks out. Move on!";
```

Or an even better way to handle this using an `$errors` array. The idea is that with each error one runs into a value is set in the `$errors` array.  So if the `$errors` array is empty after the checks? You know the input is valid. If there are `$errors` then you know there are problems & you can just echo the contents of the array via a `foreach` loop:

```
// VERIFICATION
$errors = array();
if ($userlength < 10 || $userlength > 20) {
    $errors[] = "Username Error";
}
if ($emailength < 7 || $emailength > 30) {
    $errors[] = "Email Error";
}
if ($passlength < 5 || $passlength > 32) {
    $errors[] = "Password Error";
}
if ($password != $repassword) {
    $errors[] = "Passwords Do Not Match";
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    $was_word = count($errors) > 1 ? "were" : "was";
    $error_word = count($errors) > 1 ? "errors" : "error";
    echo "There " . $was_word . count($errors) . " " . $error_word . "<br />";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
      echo $error . "<br />";
    }
    die();
}

echo "If you get to here, everything checks out. Move on!";
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Or OP was asking the wrong question

Comment: Yes, your last solution is better :) only pet peeve being assuming the number of errors. You should probably `count()` the `$error` before determine how many there are

Comment: Ok. But your script will say, at some point `"You have one errorS"`

Answer (score 1):

The `else` is only related to the last `if` - so it will be executed EVERY TIME, the last `if` fails - independent of the 3 ifs ahead.

Use `if`,`else if`,`else if`,`else` - or a flag,if the `else` should be executed, whenever ONE of the ifs fails. (i.e. if you want to display ALL errors at the same time - and just continue if there wasn't one)

Comment: How would I recreate this so that it would be able to show all three errors at the same time, assuming you got them all incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your *else* belongs only to the last *if* branch, getting executed whenever the passwords are not equal.
Possilbe fix if you want multiple error messages to be possible (otherwise use *else if* s):

```
// VERIFICATION
$success = true;
if ($userlength < 10 || $userlength > 20) {
    Echo "Username Error";
    $success = false;
}
if ($emailength < 7 || $emailength > 30) {
    Echo "Email Error";
    $success = false;
}
if ($passlength < 5 || $passlength > 32) {
    Echo "Password Error";
    $success = false;
}
if ($password != $repassword) {
    Echo "Passwords Do Not Match";
    $success = false;
}
if ($success) {
    Echo "This still runs!?!?!!?";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but I found it and thought I would share my opinion (How I did the same thing).

If you don't want to use ajax you can stop reading as this solution will use ajax.

```
$username = $_POST["u"];
$email = $_POST["e"];
$password = $_POST["p"];
$repassword = $_POST["vp"];
$userlength = strlen($username);
$emailength = strlen($email);
$passlength = strlen($password);

// VERIFICATION
if ($userlength < 10 || $userlength > 20) {
    Echo "Username_error";
    exit();
} elseif ($emailength < 7 || $emailength > 30) {
    Echo "Email_error";
    exit();
} elseif ($passlength < 5 || $passlength > 32) {
    Echo "Passworderror";
    exit();
} elseif ($password != $repassword) {
    Echo "Password_match_error";
    exit();
}
echo "signup_success";
```

Then you want to run an ajax script that checks what is being echoed and tells you directly what's wrong.

```
function signup(){
    var u = $("#username").value;
    var e = $("#email").value;
    var p = $("#password").value;
    var vp = $("#verificationpassword").value;
    var errors = $("$errormessages");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p == "" || vp == "" ){
        errors.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                    errors.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    $("#signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p+"&vp="+vp);
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to add it to a form and submit it, you just add a button that runs the function signup onclick.